# Installer StartMenu Shortcut points to folder, not .exe

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have followed every tutorial I can find, but I keep having this problem.

The shortcut in the Start Menu, created by the installer, points to the directory my application is in, not to the actual executable.

I'm using the basic installer in Visual Studio 2010, Win XP, and I'm installing the app using "Run As" admin.

I have the PrimaryOutput(Active) in the Application Folder of the installer's File System.  Then I created a shortcut to it and moved the shortcut to the "User's Programs Menu" -> "MyCompanyName" folder.

Inspecting the "Primary Output" with right-click -> Outputs, I see two files: the MyApp.exe, and MyApp.exe.config.  I don't know if this is normal.  The "key" output is MyApp.exe.

I'm using a custom installer, whose PrimaryOutput is in the Application Folder/bin folder in the installer's FileSystem view.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  I have been fighting this for hours with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you choose the desktop icon after you have to tell it where to point at.

Comment: when you are creating you installer,After you get all files in application folder right-click the exe and choose create shortcut,then move that shortcut to the folder user desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted everything from the installer "File System" and started over.  Although I had tried that before, this time it worked.

The problem I observed has not recurred.

Thanks to everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the programname.exe file and select 'Create Shortcut' there, not on the folder.  The shortcut will be saved in your Programs Folder, 'C'ut it and paste it to your Start Menu folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Setup & Deployment, VS Installer project correct?

In our Installer, we specify a new folder (with a shortcut file inside), under "File System on Target Machine" -> "User's Programs Menu".

The Target of this shortcut is the Primary output of the Windows app project of the solution.